# Copying Content from one sheet to another based on a master reference list VBA

Tags: vba, excel, reference, copy

I'm trying to format a report and copy the important values onto a blank sheet.

I am using a master list  of references to decide which information is important or not. The unique references for each item is store on a Sheet called "Master List" in column B, I want my macro to scan this list and see if it can find a match in the "Raw Data" sheet and copy that matching Row onto the "Report" sheet.

The attempt I have make does all the initial formatting fine, but then stumbles when it hits the first While command. I've tried a couple of different ways to do this and I can't seem to make it work. In the words of Princess Leia, help me Stack Overflow you're my only hope

```
Dim RD As Worksheet, Report As Worksheet, Masterlist As Worksheet
Dim LSearchRow As Integer
Dim LCopytoRow As Integer
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim SearchItem As String


Set RD = Sheets("Raw Data")
Set Report = Sheets("Report")
Set Masterlist = Sheets("Master List")


LCopytoRow = 1
LSearchRow = 1

RD.Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    Columns("B:D").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    Columns("D:Q").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    Columns("E:I").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.ClearContents


While Len(Range("A" * CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0
    SearchItem = Masterlist.Range("B" & k).End(xlUp).Row
    If Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = Masterlist.Range("B" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value Then
        Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
        Selection.Cut

        Report.Select
        Rows(CStr(LCopytoRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopytoRow)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        LCopytoRow = LCopytoRow + 1

        RD.Select
    End If

    LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

Wend
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's because you never define `k` so it's looking in `MasterList.Range("B" & k)` where `k` = `0` and because cell B0 doesn't exist you're getting an error.

Comment: Ah I had originally defined it but changed  the way it was structured! I will change it now and see if that helps! Thank you!

Comment: But your `SearchItem` doesn't make any sense, since (if you replace `k` with `Masterlist.Rows.Count`, you'll always end up with the same `Searchitem`, but that doesn't even matter because you never reference `SearchItem` again....  Simply remove that line because its never used or referenced?

Comment: Ah yeah, also a by product of the first problem. With the entire line gone however I don't get any errors but nothing copies across to the new sheet.  I had originally wanted to use Searchitem on a loop for the macro to find an item from the list and search for it in the raw data and when found copy across

Answer (score 0):

Hard to test without sample data, but something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsMstr As Worksheet
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsRprt As Worksheet
    Dim aMasterFilter As Variant

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsMstr = wb.Sheets("Master List")
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Raw Data")
    Set wsRprt = wb.Sheets("Report")

    wsData.Range("A:A,C:E,H:U,W:AA").EntireColumn.Delete xlToLeft
    wsData.Columns("C").EntireColumn.ClearContents
    wsData.AutoFilterMode = False

    aMasterFilter = Application.Transpose(wsMstr.Range("B1", wsMstr.Cells(wsMstr.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value)
    With wsData.Range("A1", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 1, aMasterFilter, xlFilterValues
        .EntireRow.Copy wsRprt.Range("A1")
        .EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much! I've spent far longer on this than I would like to admit, got stuck in a bit of a logic loop in my head